# Where are "queued" Azure Event Grid Blob trigger event messages stored and how can I clear them?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

Pardon if my terminology is a little off; I'm new to this.

I have created an Azure Event Grid subscription which triggers an event whenever I upload a file to blob storage.  I have an Azure Function which responds to this event.  I've got this all working finally, but I have a slough of left-over messages from previous (bad) uploads that are failing periodically (as viewed from the Logs window in the Azure portal for the associated Azure Function).  It's as if they're stored in a queue somewhere and retried periodically, though I'm not sure if that's how it works.

In any case, what I want to be able to do is purge any in-transit or queued events, but I don't know where to find them to do this.  As far as I know they're just floating about in the ether.

How can I purge these events so they don't keep triggering my Azure Function at random times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Event Grid will automatically retry delivery of the message if anything other then a 200 or 202 (OK/Accepted) is returned when a delivery attempt is made.  By default it will try again for 24 hours and it uses an exponential backup that adds additional time in between each request until it gives up. What you're seeing is that default process running. (You can also configure a dead letter handling with a storage account so the undelivered messages get stored somewhere if it eventually fails).

What you are likely looking for is the Retry Policy you can create when creating a subscription. Pretty sure you can set the number of maximum delivery attempts to 1 so it won't retry (and without dead letter support turned on the message would essentially be dropped).  More details on this can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/manage-event-delivery#set-retry-policy

I'm not aware of any way to "dequeue" already submitted messages without that retry policy already in place - you may have to delete and recreate the subscription to that event grid topic.

Comment: Thank you very much, this does clear some things up. Though there currently appears to be a bug in which any attempt to change the timeout will completely break my event grid subscription, delete its filters, etc., and the only way to get it working again is to recreate it from the Azure Functions area of the portal.

Comment: Removing and recreating the subscription didn't solve the problem for me. Previous failed events were apparently still in the retry queue and the Event-Grid tried to run them.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @JoshCarlisle's answer and more clear to the [Event Grid message delivery and retry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry) document:

The dead-lettering enables a special case in the retry policy logic. 
In the case of the dead-lettering is **turn-on** and subscriber failed with a **HttpStatusCode.BadRequest**, the Event Grid will stop a retrying process and the event is sent to the dead-letter endpoint. This error code indicates, that the delivery will never succeed.

the following code snippet shows some properties in the dead-letter message:

```
"deadLetterReason": "UndeliverableDueToHttpBadRequest",
"deliveryAttempts": 1,
"lastDeliveryOutcome": "BadRequest",
"lastHttpStatusCode": 400,
```

the following list shows some of the status codes where the Event Grid will continue in the retrying process:

```
HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable
HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout
HttpStatusCode.NotFound
HttpStatusCode.Conflict
HttpStatusCode.Forbidden
HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented
HttpStatusCode.Gone
```

Example of the some dead-letter properties, when the *HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout*:

```
"deadLetterReason":"MaxDeliveryAttemptsExceeded",
"deliveryAttempts":3,
"lastDeliveryOutcome":"TimedOut",
"lastHttpStatusCode":408,
```

Now, you can see the above two difference cases described in the *deadLetterReason* property such as "**UndeliverableDueToHttpBadRequest**" vs "**MaxDeliveryAttemptsExceeded**"

One more thing:

- When the dead-lettering is turn-on, the Event Grid will **NOT** deliver a dead-letter message to the dead-letter endpoint immediately, but after ~300 seconds. I hope this is a bug and it will be fix soon. 
  Practically, if the subscriber failed for instance *HttpStatusCode.BadRequest*, we can not wait for 5 minutes the event from the container storage, it must be an event driven close to the real-time.

Comment: The 5 minute buffer for dead-letter messages is by design.

Comment: @dbarkol What is the reason to have the 5 minutes delay? My test shows, this is not for batching process, why it can not be just 60 seconds? Can we configure it?

Comment: It's to help reduce the number of blob operations. There isn't a way to configure it.

Comment: @dbarkol This part is missing in the MSDN document, so I have just created an issue, https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/14706  Thanks